# Process Large and Complex XML file into Solr

Tags: solr, xpath-2.0, dataimporthandler

I wish to process XML file which contains very large and complex schema. I know we can use DataImportHndler to process such kind of data, but while retrieving the result we are not get the data in same way as in file. I want the result in XML as well in JSON format.

The structure of xml is much complex so that i am unable to use XPath Parser for result. 
Is any other solution to my problem? I think couple of us met to this scenario while processing big and complex data.

bellow is the just a example of XML file schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="chapter">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="sentence" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="report">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="toc" />
            <xs:element ref="chapter" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="sentence">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="toc">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tocitem" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="substructure">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="substructures">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element ref="substructure" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="tocitem">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="chapter" type="xs:IDREF" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: It's very simple if you just forget about DataImportHandler and write some code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update request handler which transforms your complex XML into the standard Solr document format. The request handler might look like this:

```
  <requestHandler name="/update/xslt" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="tr">myComplexToSolr.xsl</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

The `tr` parameter points to a XSLT file which will convert the input XML to the standard Solr format.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, actually I am more concerned about the query result from solr, which returns result in solr doc format onlyor we can override the result using XSLT(as per my knowledge). Can we get the result in same format as it is in file?

Comment: Same format as in file: which file? How are you adding documents to the Solr index? Are the documents added using the data import handler, or are they added by posting XML?

Comment: I am processing my complex XML into solr for search purpose. Solr accept the document only in specific format. That I achieve through the DIH. Once I queried, its gives us the result as in solr document format only. I am looking to get that result into same format as it is in the file.

Comment: Fundamentally, the information which defines the structure of your original complex XML is not stored in Solr, and the data import handler process is not reversible. Other than using XSLT as described above, you could store your original XML and use the results from the Solr search to find your original XML document.